Is special piping required for laundry water?
Are any special pipes required to prevent the laundry detergent from corroding the pipes? Is laundry detergent any more damaging than dishwashing liquid?

Anything that would harm your plumbing would do terrible things to your clothes.

Will not damaged any pipes, but soaps plus food fats plus hair plus fibres from clothes might clog  the pipes requiring cleaning/snaking.

If laundry waste were corrosive and required a special material for plumbing, then the entire waste plumbing system would need to be made of that material. Or is it your family's expert opinion that it's only corrosive in that one pipe and magically becomes non-corrosive when it enters the main line shared with the test of the waste? Lol ... :p

I'm not aware of any laundry scenario where different drain piping would be required compared to what's used for the rest of the drain plumbing of the house.  Why do you think it would need anything different, as it's not really any different in corrosive nature than any other household detergent that might be used.

My family thinks it's a problem, and I need to disprove them.

@blahahaaahahaa urine and other human waste is also corrosive, so the entire plumbing system is designed to be chemically resistant

There is no danger of household laundry detergent corroding home plumbing systems.  If there were, plumbing codes would prescribe materials to prevent it.  You can search for such requirements (in vain, I submit) the 2024 National Standard Plumbing Code Illustrated at  https://epubs.iapmo.org/NSPC/2024/
(As for your family's protests, proving a negative for this would be exhausting.  It would make more sense for them to prove such a danger exists.  If, as I suspect, the "evidence" is anecdotal - as in "my buddy knew a guy who had his laundry drain pipe rupture the day he washed his work clothes" - ask them what would explain why no one else has this problem.)
For what it's worth, I once worked in a university lab building which had two separate waste water systems, one normal, made of PVC, and one called "acid waste" which was made of glass.  There were washing machines in some of the labs (veterinary was one, as I recall), that emptied into the normal waste line.
